# BigQuery's UDF doesn't support synchronous query by API or how to use?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery supports UDF since August 25, 2015.

I found jobs.query can use UDF by userDefinedFunctionResources
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query

but does not queries support UDF?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query

I want to use UDF by synchronous query, how to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs are objects that manage **asynchronous** tasks. So this is not possible in synchronous mode.

- One method listed by you is creating a Job for Bigquery, there indeed you have Job configuration object, and you can use UDF.
- The other is a simple query synchronous interface, where you don't have Job configuration object, and you cannot use UDF.

Comment: Note that you can create the query job with the jobs.insert method and then use jobs.getQueryResults to poll for completion just as you would with the "synchronous" interface. That's one way to get polling behavior *and* use UDFs.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to confirm only way for use udf is jobs.insert. I understand it, I'll try poll completion.